# Why can't I initialize a static class member in a common header file?

Tags: c++, static-members, multiple-definition-error

Suppose I have a header only library. I have simplified it to something like this.

Header only library `Foo.hpp`

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

struct Foo{
    static const int A;
};

const int Foo::A = 100;

void SomeMethod(){
   // do some stuff
}
#endif
```

Then, I have parent class (`Parent.hpp` and `Parent.cpp`):

```
#ifndef PARENT_HPP
#define PARENT_HPP

#include "Foo.hpp"

struct Parent {
        virtual void my_method();
};
#endif
```

Child class (`Child.hpp` and `Child.cpp`)

```
#ifndef CHILD_HPP
#define CHILD_HPP

#include "Parent.hpp"
#include "Foo.hpp"

struct Child : Parent{
        void my_method();
};
#endif
```

In `my_method()`, I just print the `Foo::A` variable.

In the real code base, I have template in the header only library.

When I compile this, I got a "multiple definition" error. How to fix this?

Comment: You should provide a proper working example, and the exact error message(s) you're getting. Also, say which compiler you're using and which version of the language standard.

Comment: I tried to provide a complete (?) set of alternatives for you to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have chosen the "non-inline" mode of initializing your static member. That is perfectly legitimate, but - in this case, you need to have exactly one translation unit (e.g. compiled `.cpp` file) defining your member. Otherwise, the C++ linker sees one definition of `Foo::A` in `parent.o` and a second definition in `child.o`, and those conflict.

Thus,

#### Solution 1: Move the definition to another file

1. Create a `Foo.cpp`, which includes `Foo.hpp` and defines `Foo::A`.
2. Delete the definition from the header, so it isn't repeated in multiple locations

#### Solution 2: Make the definition conditional

This is not really recommended, but it does work.

1. Surround the definition like so:

   ```
   #ifdef FOO_A_DEFINITION
   const int Foo::A = 100;
   #endif
   ```
2. Create a `Foo.cpp`, which defines `#FOO_A_DEFINITION` and then includes `Foo.hpp`

This has the detriment of using macros, but the benefit of human users seeing the definition from the header.

#### Solution 3: Initialize in class definition

So, you are asking yourself "Why should they conflict? I want the compiler to know that they're the same variable!"

One way to do this to initialize the static member within the class body. Since this is a simple type, that's possible even with older versions of the language standard. This is also [@idmean's suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65858453/1593077):

```
class Foo {
    public:
        static const int A = 100;
};
```

There's a caveat here, which is that you're "not really" defining the static member this way. You can use it, but not in every way you would use a variable defined with solutions (1.) or (2.). See discussion here:

See a discussion of this point here:

[Defining static const integer members in class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3025997/1593077)

#### Solution 4: Inline your static member

This solution is another way to tell the compiler "it's just one definition for everybody", which only works in C++17 or later:

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo {
    public:
        inline static const int A = 100;
};
```

This looks very similar to Solution 3, but actually does something very different!

With this solution, you're actually defining the static member multiple times - in each translation unit - but are telling the compiler to only keep a single definition when linking and encountering many of them.

Solutions (1.) and (2.) behave differently from this solution (4.) when you use dynamically-linked libraries. See:

[Where to initialize static const member in c++17 or newer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65084349/1593077)

for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
class Foo {
    
    public:
        static const int A;
    
};

const int Foo::A = 100;
```

with

```
class Foo {
    
    public:
        static const int A = 100;
    
};
```

Comment: This is just a simplified case, but some other method is also defined which is not in the class. Those methods are template method.

Comment: @Bharata Well, you must inline everything you define in a header. Otherwise you'll get linker errors.

Comment: I have added the example of SomeMethod in the header hpp file. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @Bharata change `void SomeMethod(){` to `inline void SomeMethod(){`

Comment: Ok, I will try it.

Comment: When I change into this : static const int A = 100; I got undefined reference.

Comment: @Bharata Please post a [mcve] that is complete and asks a single question. This site is not a discussion forum and questions should not be extended (to different topics) except in rare circumstances.

Comment: Well, I have tried the answer to idmean and it doesn't work. But I have fixed it with adding const int Const::A. As for your suggestion for inline method, I haven't tried it.